# Codeigniter - Show Database records that are relating to the current session's User ID

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

New to codeigniter so unsure of route.
I have a user logging in to their dashboard and they can add contacts. these contacts are displayed on their dashboard, however so far it displays different user's contacts, as oppose to just the current Users ID based on their session.. my sessions are setup correctly as when a user adds a contact it is added with their current ID.. I am just unsure as to how to edit the table to display specific records

**Controller**

```html
  function getDisplayUsersTable()
 {
     
     $this->load->model('Contacts_model');

    
     $this->load->library('table');

   
     $this->table->set_heading('Check', 'Contact ID','Fullname', 'Email', 'Country', 'Gender', 'Users_ID');

    
     $style = array('table_open'  => '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">');
     $this->table->set_template($style);

     
     $contacts = $this->Contacts_model->getUsers()->result_array();

      $tableData = '';




      foreach($contacts as $contact) {

    


        array_unshift($contact, '<input type="checkbox" label="check">');

        $this->table->add_row($contact);
      }

     // generate table from query result
     return $this->table->generate();

 }
```

**Model**

```html
class Contacts_model extends CI_Model{
  Public function AddContact($data){
   $query=$this->db->insert('contacts',$data);
 }


 function getUsers()
 {
     return $this->db->get('contacts');
 }
```

**View**

```html
 <div>
               <?php


               echo $contacttable;?>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WHERE close in your model:

```
function getUsers($user_id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('contacts', array('user_id' => $user_id))->result_array();
}
```

and in controller:

```
$contacts = $this->Contacts_model->getUsers($this->session->user_id);
```

Comment: I think this should work, however when I change to this the table comes up empty when it shouldn't as there are records there.. massively appreciate the help as you've put me in the right direction being a newbie

Comment: I think you are using the wrong user_id definition in your new code. Do a var_dump($this->session->userdata()); then define what is the var name of the session user id and then use it in your code

Comment: you are absolutely right, im dumb, was a case of 'user_id' and users_id', it is working now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a **model method** that looks for contacts related to the user. I'm making some assumptions here but it could be something like this

```
 function getUsersContacts()
 {
     //assuming 'userID' is the name of the session item and 
     //that 'id' is the name of the field in the contacts field

     $id = $this->session->userID; 
     //return results from the model
     return $this->db
                 ->get_where('contacts', array('id' => $id))
                 ->result_array();
 }
```

`get_where()` combines the `get()` and `where()` Query Builder methods into one.
IMO, models should return the data from the query and not just a `CI_DB_result` object that the controller uses to retrieve data. With that in mind the controller then uses this code.

```
$contacts = $this->Contacts_model->getUsersContacts();
```

Comment: Your model function is not respecting the MVC model

Comment: I beg your pardon? How so?

Comment: i have attempted this to no avail.. 
im new to codeigniter so i dont really understand this section
return $this->db
                 ->get_where('contacts', array('id' => $id))
                 ->result_array();
 }
if you could elaborate please? thanks alot btw

Comment: What is the name of the session item that holds the user's id?

Comment: @DFriend this $id = $this->session->userID;  should not be in a model function. the model role is just retrieving the data not dealing with session. And also, let's say you will need to retrieve related contacts to a user in your admin panel or any place else, should you create another function and give it another source of user_id?

Comment: the sessions table is 'ci_sessions'

Comment: @JamesMcMahon, As long as sessions are working that doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: @Oussama, Your assertion that models should not access session data is not correct. It is very common for models to manipulate session data and even retrieve `$_POST` data. I can provide evidence of such in several highly regarded third-party CI libraries. The OP states the wish to get data based on session data. While you make a valid argument that the method would be more reusable (which passing the id in an argument accomplishes) but there isn't any reason to assume that the method must be reusable. Either way, my approach doesn't come close to violating MVC principles.

Comment: @DFriend here is small definition of the model by apple "(...). Because model objects represent knowledge and expertise related to a specific problem domain, they can be reused in similar problem domains. Ideally, a model object should have no explicit connection to the view objects that present its data and allow users to edit that data—it should not be concerned with user-interface and presentation issues." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Another definition: The model is the central component of the MVC pattern. It expresses the application's behavior in terms of the area of expertise that needs to be examined to solve a problem, independent of the user interface. It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application. So, how does using data from a session create an explicit connection to the view?

Answer (score 0):

> I use the session in the model to match what is in the database table like I have in the function should work

```
public function getContacts()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('contacts');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```